# jQuery - Find and scroll to an element dynamically based on its text content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a 'jargon buster' which has a list of jargon terms at the top, and below that is an individual div for each of those terms, containing the term as a title, and its explanation underneath.

I'm trying to write a function which, when you click on one of those jargon terms at the top, finds the div with that term as an h3 title, and scrolls to it.

I don't know what these terms will be in advance so can't rely on hard coding. It's also possible that some terms may actually contain all of the letters from another term - for example, one term may be 'intellectual property' and another could be 'intellectual property lawyer'. So the function needs to find an exact match.

So far, I've managed to write a function which converts to lower case and matches the clicked term up with the h3 of the same name. What I can't work out is how to use that to scroll to it. Does anyone have any suggestions? I could well be going at this completely the wrong way.

**Example list of jargon terms:**

```
<div class="jargonBusterDropDown">
    <div class="textWrapper">
        <p>attorney</p>
        <p>copyright</p>
        <p>chartered</p>
        <p>intellectual property</p>
        <p>intellectual property lawyer</p>
        <p>licensing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example of a full jargon term div**

```
        <div class="fullWidthContentCard jargonBusterCard">
            <div class="fullWidthContentCard__title">
                <h3>Attorney <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="fullWidthContentCard__content">
                <p>DESCRIPTION GOES HERE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My JS**

```
$('.jargonBusterDropDown p').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var titles = [];
    $('.fullWidthContentCard__title h3').each(function(i, e){
        titles.push($(e).text().slice(0, -1).toLowerCase());
    });
    var elementToScrollTo = titles.filter(function(title){
        return val === title;
    });
    elementToScrollTo = elementToScrollTo.toString();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(object).offset().top}, 300 /*duration in milisec*/);
```

where `object` is the one you have found. If you are in each() function you should write `this`.

Edit: Full solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.jargonBusterDropDown p').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        console.log(val);
        $('.fullWidthContentCard__title h3').each(function(i, e){
            if($(e).text().slice(0, -1).toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0) // val is found
            {
                console.log($(e));
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(e).offset().top}, 300 /*duration in milisec*/);
                return false; // Use this if you want to stop and scroll to the first object found. Otherwise you will scroll to the last.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the element to scroll to, possible using the [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), be careful for case sensitivity with that!

After that it's a simple scroll to the offset of the element retrieved with `element.offset().top`

```js
$('.jargonBusterDropDown p').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.fullWidthContentCard__title h3:contains(' + val + ')').offset().top
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
.jargonBusterDropDown {
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jargonBusterDropDown">
  <div class="textWrapper">
    <p>attorney</p>
    <p>copyright</p>
    <p>chartered</p>
    <p>intellectual property</p>
    <p>intellectual property lawyer</p>
    <p>licensing</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fullWidthContentCard jargonBusterCard">
  <div class="fullWidthContentCard__title">
    <h3>attorney <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="fullWidthContentCard__content">
    <p>DESCRIPTION GOES HERE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```